# Jquery full calendar

Tags: jquery-plugins, fullcalendar

How do I remove the past dates from the full calendar. SO when the calendar loads it should display only current month's date. I could disable the past dates but I need to remove it from the current month.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the solution for removing dates, but this is what I'm using for when someone clicks on a date and trying to make an appointment thats in the past.

```
var date = new Date();
select: function(start, end, allDay) {
    if(start < date) {
        alert('Cannot select past dates.');
        return;
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the property visStart, this will let you control what the first visible day on the calendar is. You can set that to DateTime.Now() (c#) or Now = new Date() (javascript)

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/views/View_Object/

This will stop the past dates from showing up the calendar.